# webscraping no me imprime los valores numéricos que me traigo de una web solo tres puntos... acá el código que corre bien

Tags: php

aca esta el codigo solo de copiar y pegar como dije funciona bien imprime los datos solo que donde esta el valor numerico del dolar eso no lo imprime solo me sale ... puntos

por favor espero su pronta respuesta tengo full coriosidad por que no funciona algo tam simple gracias saludos desde venezuela...............................

https://github.com/elnycoolen/webscraping

Comment: disculpa puedes ser un poco mas especifico no entendi ojo las variables que tengo nombradas alli fue solo para probar lo cierto es que si me treae lo que quiero pero en la parte donde sale el monto de a como esta el dolar no me lo muestra osea nada numerico puedes indicarme exactamente a que te refieres gracias

Comment: Saludos @coolen, que extraño, no recuerdo haber puesto ese comentario XD, pero bueno lo mas recomendable es que el código relevante lo ingreses directamente en tu pregunta y ya si quieres puedes complementar con el enlace a github, esto por si el enlace deja de existir. Puedes darle una revisada a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para más información. ;)